# Assembly program that finds second smalest value in array

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, x86-16

this is my code that supposed to sorting the array in the way that to find the smallest number but when I'm running that on the 8086 assembly  I don't see any result  or any thing else but I guess the problem is that my code cannot get out of the loop or something like that is that right?
again I'm saying that the problem on my code is that it doesn't show any result on the window and my program must find the second smallest number in the array.can someone help me to fix the it?

```
org 100h

; add your code here    
DATA SEGMENT
ARR DB 5,3,7,1,9,2,6,8,4
LEN DW $-ARR
SMALL DB ?
SECOND DB ?
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA CS:CODE
START:
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
LEA SI,ARR
MOV AL,ARR[SI]
MOV SMALL,AL
MOV CX,LEN
REPEAT1:
MOV AL,ARR[SI]
CMP SMALL,AL
JL NOCHANGE
MOV SMALL,AL
NOCHANGE:
INC SI
LOOP REPEAT1
LEA SI,ARR
MOV AL,ARR[SI]
MOV SECOND,AL
MOV CX,LEN
REPEAT2:
MOV AL,ARR[SI]
CMP SECOND,AL
JL SKIP
CMP SMALL,AL
JGE SKIP
MOV SECOND,AL
SKIP:
INC SI
LOOP REPEAT2
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START

ret
```

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: have you tried step debugging it?

Comment: i don't know how to do it

Comment: Also you do not do anything with the result, of course nothing will be printed.

Comment: so what should i add?

Comment: edit your post and comment your code, otherwise no one will read that mess

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering at this point in your class if you are supposed to be able to output numbers as opposed to looking at register values while running a debugger.

As an alternative, insert the commented line into your code to return the value as an error code:

```
        LOOP    REPEAT2
        MOV     AH,4CH
        MOV     AL,SECOND     ;insert this line
        INT     21H
        CODE    ENDS
        END     START
```

After assembling and linking the program, run it from a DOS console window (Command prompt). Assume you named it "myprogram.com". Then use these commands:

```
myprogram
echo %errorlevel%
```

The errorlevel is the value in AL when using AH=4CH and INT 21H. This only works for single byte values, but that's what you have in this case.

Otherwise you would have to add code to convert the value to decimal and output the result. If these are singe digit values, then the output code is simple:

```
        MOV     DL,SECOND
        ADD     DL,030H
        MOV     AH,002H
        INT     21H
        MOV     DL,00DH
        MOV     AH,002H
        INT     21H
        MOV     DL,00AH
        MOV     AH,002H
        INT     21H
```

or use a string:

```
SECOND  DB      ?
STRNG   DB      000H,00DH,00AH,'$'     ;insert this line
        ...
        MOV     AL,SECOND
        ADD     AL,30
        MOV     STRNG,AL
        MOV     DX,OFFSET STRNG
        MOV     AH,009H
        INT     21H
```